# Extract SparkSession from SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a list to a dataframe as part of my tests using the `toDF` function but the problem is I am unable to create/retrieve `SparkSession`. Hence I cannot use the `toDF` method. However, I can create a `SparkContext`.

Is there any way I can get `SparkSession` from `SparkContext` or is there a way to load the list into a dataframe besides the `toDF` method?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Can you post the code you use to create your SparkContext instance?

Comment: If you are using Spark version less than 2.0 then SparkSession will not available

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below working code syntax.
Please verify the version of spark which you are using as its available only for 2.0 or higher. 
In case you are getting some other error please post it on the thread.

```
val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .master("local")
          .appName("ReadDataFromTextFile")
          .getOrCreate()

val file_2 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("d:/small_projects/spark/cobrand_config.json")
```